# How to deploy ElasticSearch to production?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have downloaded and build code around ElasticSearch.
It works in staging server. I unzipped the download to folder C:\ElasticSearch\elasticsearch-1.1.1

Now I see \bin \config \data \lib \logs \pluggins folders and License.txt file in there.
The total size of unzipped folder is 4.9GB!!!

Which of these do I really need to copy to production?

I need to run it as a windows service.

Could anyone please help me here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This depends mainly on what you want to keep for the production. If you want only the data then copy the folder data. If you still want to the same config and pluggins then copy the whole folder exept logs.

However you should be aware that putting elastic search in production is usually way more complicated than that, it often needs to be in cluster and have special configuration on servers.